# Matrix of double values to RGB image in .NET

Tags: c#

If I have a 2D Matrix of double values (between 0 and 1) and I want to show it as an RGB image I can easily do it in Matlab just by using imagesc(Matrix).

Example: a double array with values from 0 to 3600 (0, 1, 2,... ,3600) normalized between 0 and 1 and then accommodated to a matrix(grid) with 60 X 60 nodes where each node has its own double value is easliy shown in matlab by using imagesc(Matrix) and here is the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o5ghfr58wu4t342/untitled.png. As you can see here each node has its own double value expressed as an RGB color in matlab.

I want to achieve the same result but using c#. I dont know what matlab developers did under the hood and so I dont know how should I exactly do it in c#. Namely I want to do a conversion of matrix of double values to an RGB image same as matlab is doing using imagesc(Matrix).

[Updated]

```
private Color generateRGB(double X)
{
    Color color;
    if (X >= 0.5) //red and half of green colors
    {
        int Red = (int)((2 * X - 1) * 255);
        int Green = (int)((2 - 2 * X) * 255);
        int Blue = 0;
        color = Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, Blue);
    }
    else  // blue and half of green colors
    {
        int Red = 0;
        int Green = (int)((2 * X) * 255);
        int Blue = (int)((1 - 2 * X) * 255);
        color = Color.FromArgb(Red, Green, Blue);
    }
    return color;
}
```

The code above is based on this method: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bvs3a9m9nc0rk5e/20131121_143044%20%281%29.jpg

Another way that I tried:

I have used an HSVtoRGB conversion algorithm. Knowing that my values are at [0,1] interval, Im extending this interval to [0, 360] in order to use the algorithm for converting HSV to RGB. Im using s and v equal to 1 in my case. Here is the code for better explanation.

```
  private Color generateRGB(double X)
    {
        Color color;

        int red;
        int green;
        int blue;
        HsvToRgb(X*360,1,1,out red,out green,out blue);

        color = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);

        return color;
    }
```

Comment: create a bitmap and do set pixel on each

Comment: @xXx: don't you know how to draw images with C# (using, for example, GDI+), or don't you just know how to do the color mapping?

Comment: Of course I know how to use GDI+. But tell me how to convert a double value to an RGB Color ?! I am using HSV2RGB with H = double value for each note, S and V = 1 and the results are here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u873vabnpshbo7q/HSV%203600.png . As you can see it is not same as the result from matlab.

Comment: That result is taken using double values (1, 2, 3,...,3600) normalized between 0 and 1 and accomodated in a 60 X 60 matrix. For each node I take the double value and I call HSV3RGB(double value, 1,1) and this returns a Color. Using this Color I set the pixel value of the bitmap but the result is not as the imagesc of matlab

Comment: @xXx: your effort to extend your question shows that you might not have have read my answer? Or maybe there is something unclear  with it?

Comment: I just read it. I will analyze it. My first pass through the answer was not clear enough but I will keep on analyzing it. Thnx a lot for the answer. If I have any question related to that answer I will ask you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a short look into the Matlab manual, it tells you that "imagesc"

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html

works with the current colormap:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

You have to build such a thing by yourself in C#, it is just a linear array holding the colors as RGB values you want to use in your image. If you want exactly the same colors in your C# solution, you have to export the values from Matlab (for example, for the default color map) and import them into C#.

So when the colormap has m entries, take each value x from your double array and scale it to an integer range from 0 to k-1:

```
int colorindex = (int)(x*k);
if(colorindex==k)   // handle the case x==1.0
   colorindex--;
```

This gives you the index into the colormap table holding the associated RGB values.